# Ansible Variables: Unexpected behaviour by set_fact on overwriting

Tags: ansible

I discovered some unexpected behaviour of the `set_fact` module of Ansible while overwriting an existent variable.

I tried to set up following "code" (example in JavaScript) with Ansible:

```
let old_var = "test"
let cache_var = old_var
let new_var = "hacked"

console.log(old_var) // "test"
console.log(cache_var) // "test"
console.log(new_var) // "hacked"

old_var = new_var

console.log(old_var) // "hacked"
console.log(cache_var) // "test"
console.log(new_var) // "hacked"
```

This is my result:

```
---

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    old_var: test
    cache_var: "{{ old_var }}"
    new_var: hacked
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: old_var
    - debug:
        var: cache_var
    - debug:
        var: new_var
    - set_fact:
        old_var: "{{ new_var }}"
    - debug:
        var: old_var
    - debug:
        var: cache_var
    - debug:
        var: new_var
```

But the output of Ansible was unexpected to me:

```
PLAY [127.0.0.1] ************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "old_var": "test"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "cache_var": "test"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "new_var": "hacked"
}

TASK [set_fact] *************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "old_var": "hacked"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "cache_var": "hacked"
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "new_var": "hacked"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=8    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Can someone please explain, why `set_fact` overwrites `cache_var` too, and can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a fix: You need to set the depending fact with `set_fact` too, fixed example is:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    old_var: test
    new_var: hacked
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        cache_var: "{{ old_var }}"
    - debug:
        var: old_var
    - debug:
        var: cache_var
    - debug:
        var: new_var
    - set_fact:
        old_var: "{{ new_var }}"
    - debug:
        var: old_var
    - debug:
        var: cache_var
    - debug:
        var: new_var
```

Maybe there is a better solution but this works.